# 2nd Order Perturbation Theory General Matrix

Tags: matrices, perturbation-theory

I Have a hamilton matrix in perturbation form ($H=H_{o}+H'$):

$
H= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&-2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&c&0\\c&0&0\\0&0&c\end{bmatrix}
$

I found the **exact** eigenvalues the traditional way: $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ yielding

$ \lambda=c-2$

$ \lambda=2-(c^2+1)^{1/2}$

$ \lambda=2+(c^2+1)^{1/2}$

$ $

**How would I find the eigenvalues using 2nd order perturbation theory?**

$ $

Answer (score 0):

For the first order. Let $\lambda(c)=f(c)$ and $H=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $f(c)=f(0)+(d\lambda/dc)(0)c+o(c)$. Note that $\det(A-\lambda(c)I_3+cH)=0$. By the implicit function theorem, $(d\lambda/dc)(0)=\dfrac{tr(H.adj(A-\lambda(0)I_3))}{tr(adj(A-\lambda(0)I_3))}$.

When $\lambda(0)=-2$, $\lambda(c)=-2+\dfrac{15}{15}c+o(c)=-2+c+o(c)$.

When $\lambda(0)=1$, $\lambda(c)=1+o(c)$.

When $\lambda(0)=3$, $\lambda(c)=3+o(c)$.

To obtain the second order, it "remains" to calculate the derivative with respect to $c$ in $c=0$ of the function $\dfrac{tr(H.adj(A-\lambda(c)I_3+cH))}{tr(adj(A-\lambda(c)I_3+cH))}$. Good luck!